# Why Mandelstam variables in Minkowski do not cover the whole allowed space?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, kinematics, metric-tensor, conservation-laws, scattering

It was mentioned by N.Arkani-Hamed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uPrlD0vorzk that Mandelstam variables in Minkowski signature $(+---)$ do not cover that whole allowed space of $s$, $t$, whereas in some other signature, namely, $(++--)$ they do.

My question is - How can one see the domain of $s$, $t$ of dissallowed values?

There is  a constraint imposed by conservation of momentum ($s + t + u = 0$), but it only fixes the $u$ in terms of $s, t$.

Comment: I thought that $s+t+u=4m^2$ for equal mass particles.

Comment: Which minute in video?

Comment: @mikestone in these lectures Arkani-Hamed works with  massless particles, now I need to think, whether it is crucial or not

Comment: @Qmechanic 1:06:15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mandelstam variables $s, t,$ and $u$ are mostly used in $2 \to 2$ scattering and $1 \to 3$ decays. As for $2 \to 2$ scattering with initial momenta $p_1$ and $p_2$ and final momenta $p_3$ and $p_4$, they are defined as
$s = (p_1 + p_2)^2 = (p_3 + p_4)^2$
$t = (p_1 - p_3)^2 = (p_2 - p_4)^2$
$u = (p_1 - p_4)^2 = (p_2 - p_3)^2$

They satisfy
$s + t + u = \sum_j m_j^2$
where $m_j$ are the invariant masses of the particles.

The Mandelstam variables correspond to particular Feynman diagrams where momentum in the propagator has invariant $p_\mu^2 = s, t,$ or $u$.
The $s$-channel is an annihilation process and the intermediate state has $p_\mu^2 = s \ge 0$, i.e. it is timelike.
The $t$- and $u$-channels are scattering processes and have $t \le 0$ and $u \le 0$, i.e. they are spacelike.

Note: here I assume the Minkowski metric tensor as $\eta_{\mu \nu} = diag(1, -1, -1, -1)$.